# How to quickly resolve a value from noise around a signal?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, data-analysis, kalman-filter

Kalman filter seems to be slow in resolving a steady signal.

Is there a way to apply Ito calculus (stochastic calculus) to resolve the signal quicker?

---

The data takes a minute or longer to converge using a Kalman filter at 1hz sampling.

Comment: Do you have a picture or some characterization of your data?

Comment: added a description

Comment: Where? I see no description. A graph would be an excellent thing to add. Also, any context about sampling rate, physical units, etc.